# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I recently started to learn spring mvc and I got stuck at the beginning. 
I have a newbie question but I didn't find any solution yet, or in other worlds; none of found solution worked. 
So, I try to make my first simple spring mvc application that prints some text after clicking the link but when i run application i get `http 404` and in glassfish logs; `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'example'`

I think that I messed something with configuration but I cannot figure out what ;/
Here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

example-servlet.xml;

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="controller" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

and HelloWorldController class;

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "Hello world spring";
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

I have `hello.jsp` inside `WEB-INF/jsp` and `index.jsp`, `web.xml` and `example-servlet.xml` inside `WEB-INF`. 
I would much appreciate for any help.
thank you from advance.
@EDIT:
Request mapping works like charm but still welcome page isn't working. 
My project structure looks like this:

```
-webapp
-WEB-INF
--jsp
---hello.jsp
--example-servlet.xml
--web.xml
-index.jsp
```

tl;dr
I have my welcome page `index.jsp` in `webapp` directory and rest in `WEB-INF` and `WEB-INF/jsp`
I have added welcome-page to web.xml:

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

And still after typing `http://localhost:8080/testApp/` get http 404.
@EDIT:
When I request `http://localhost:8080/testApp/index.jsp` everything works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and its appropriate namespace declarations from your context configuration. Without it, Spring won't register your controllers (among other things).

Also, your controller handler method is mapped to

```
@RequestMapping("/hello")
```

so the request should go to

```
/your-context-path/hello
```

Comment: thanks, after adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />` works fine but i wonder why when i use localhost:8080/testApp/ I still get 404? It shouldn't print my index.jsp? 
When I use localhost:8080/testApp/hello it works ;)

Comment: @mle Is your index.jsp declared as a welcome-file? Do you have a handler for it?

Comment: yes i have declared index.jsp as welcome file but I don't have any handler. What should I add?

Comment: @mlethys If it's declared as a `<welcome-file>` and it is located at the root of the `webcontent` folder, it should be handled by the container. No additional work is required on your behalf.

Comment: @mlethys I can't reproduce your problem. If you turn your logs to DEBUG and send your request, does Spring complain? (Spring shouldn't be involved in the request that renders `index.jsp`.)

Comment: I get only this: `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'example'`

Comment: @mlethys Ok. First, is your servlet still mapped to `/` or have you changed it to `/*`? Second, what happens if you send the request to `/testApp` rather than `/testApp/`?

Comment: It was mapped to `/` but with `/*` is still the same. If I send request to `/testApp` I get the same message (`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/testApp/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'example'`).

Comment: @mlethys Did you figure it out? I can't reproduce your problem with the `<welcome-file>`.

Comment: Not so. I just send request with index.jsp. For now it's good option.

Answer (score 0):

if someone is struggling with my problem (welcome page isn't displaying) I found some solution. 
If you have view resolver configured like this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

create your `index.jsp` in `WEB-INF/jsp` directory and create controller class for it like below:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

now If you call `http://address/yourapp/` index.jsp will be mapped.